# Question regarding galois correspondence in ${\mathbb R} /{\mathbb Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

${\rm Aut }\left({\mathbb R}/{\mathbb Q}\right)$ is trivial,  which implies there is no intermediate field between the field of rationals and field of real numbers, but we know there are infinitely many intermediate fields of $\mathbb R$ containing $\mathbb Q$.

Why I am getting an contradictions? Please explain where I went wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the other answers point out, the problem is that $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ is not a Galois extension. Their arguments are, however, incorrect: being finite is not necessary for an extension $L/K$ to be Galois, and there is a rich theory of infinite Galois extensions.

A Galois extension is an *algebraic* extension that is *normal* and *separable*. Separability is fine here, but the other two conditions do not hold:

1. $\mathbb R$ is not an algebraic extension of $\mathbb Q$. In particular, $\mathbb R$ contains transcendental extensions such as $\mathbb Q(\pi)$
2. Even if we replaced $\mathbb R$ with $\mathbb R\cap\overline{\mathbb Q}$, the extension would still not be normal. For example, it contains the real root of $X^3-2$ but none of the complex roots.

For these two reasons, one cannot apply Galois theory to the extension $\mathbb{R/Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement is wrong. The fact that $Aut(\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Q})$ is trivial does not imply that there are no intermediate fields (for example take $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2))$.

You are probably applying Galois Fundamental Theorem wrong. In the hypothesis, the Field Extension has to be a Galois extension. In particular, it has to be a normal extension, but $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Q}$ is not normal, as $x^3-p$  (for example, with $p$ prime, is irreducible by Eisenstein), has a root in $\Bbb{R}$ but does not split on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: I am pretty certain that extensions being finite is not a requirement. The field of constructive numbers, for instance, is infinite and Galois over $\Bbb Q$. The extension does have to be algebraic, though.

Comment: @Arthur yes, I am aware that there are some generalizations, but none of them are needed here. Besides, there is some debate with the definition of normality. The one I was given was that an extension is normal if it is the splitting field of a polynomial. which of course implies finiteness

Comment: This is incorrect. You cannot apply this definition of being normal to an infinite extension. By your argument, you could not apply Galois theory to $\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I see your point. I just wanted to make things simpler by using that definition but it just does not work. I'll edit it